# trimming audio file with pydub returns empty file

Tags: python, mp3, pydub

I saw another post on the same problem but it didn't help me. I have this code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

path = input("Enter path of mp3 file")
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)
start = input("At which second shall the new file begin?")
start = int(start)*1000
end = input("At which second shall the new file end?")
end = int(end)*1000
newmp3 = song[start:end]
path = path[:-5]
newmp3.export(str(path)+"n.mp3", format = "mp3")
print("New Audio File is created and saved")
```

The result it that it adds an empty mp3 to my folder. Why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: When or where did you define `path2`? The code you've provided won't run on its own. My guess is that's the issue.

Comment: That was a typo, but it did not cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your variable names :

```py
path = input("Enter path of mp3 file")
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)
```

Comment: If the issue is caused by a typo, flag the question as such.

Comment: Oh yes, there was a typo, but the problem remains